# Pytest ModuleNotFoundError during CodeBuild importing class from layer from another stack

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pytest, aws-codebuild, aws-lambda-layers

I have the following project:

1. SAM APP A with Layer containing custom modules & libraries.
2. SAM APP B with Lambda importing custom modules & libraries from layer from stack A.

Directory structure of Layer in SAM APP A is:

> layer_common/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/

This folder contains:

- libraries installed with pip
- custom module named **project_common**

SAM APP B has folder structure like this:

```
lambda_folder/
   __init__.py
   app.py
tests/
  __init__.py
  lambda_test.py
```

Lambda function code is:

```
from project_common.utils import HttpResponse

def handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
             "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "success"
    }
```

test_lambda.py has the following code:

```
import pytest
import json
import lambda_folder.app

@pytest.fixture()
def apigw_event():
    return {
       ...
    }

def test_handler(apigw_event, mocker):
    # test call lambda
    ret = lambda_folder.app.handler(apigw_event, "")
    data = json.loads(ret["body"])
    assert ret["statusCode"] == 200
```

**When I test the function with AWS console, everything works fine. Module is imported correctly and lambda runs ok.**

**When I run pipeline deploying SAM APP B, it fails at CodeBuild step** (buildspec.yml containing the following command **python -m pytest tests/ -v**).
Logs from CodeBuild is:

```
 ==================================== ERRORS ====================================
 _____ ERROR collecting tests/lambda_test.py ______
 ImportError while importing test module '/codebuild/output/src325371334/src/tests/lambda_test.py'.
 Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
 Traceback:
 /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 tests/lambda_test.py:9: in <module>
      import lambda_folder.app
 lambda_folder/app.py:5: in <module>
      from project_common.utils import HttpResponse
 E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_common'
```

**I would like to have my pytest tests importing modules from shared layer from another stack working but I didn't manage to do it so far.**

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before pytest. `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I had to install `multiple-packages`.
For me what worked was The package version you are using locally to build to should be used on codebuild side.
Locally I was working with python and on the `buildspec.yml` file on codebuild  was installing python3.
This gave an error called `ModuleNotFoundError`.